# JPA Many to one mapping using composite key

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 tables

```
PKG               TEAM
id(pk)            id
name              name
folder            filescount
                  pkg_id(fk)
                  (id,pkgid)(pk)
```

How do i create one to many mapping for above using the composite primary key in team table for jpa

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: already checked that but it seems second table has id as primary key but in my table team pk will be composite primary key made using foreign key and id

Comment: why not use `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "pkg_id")` on team and `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pkg")` on pkg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a "derived identity" by mapping your classes like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PKG")
public class Package {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String folder;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "package")
    private List<Team> teams;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class TeamId {
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "pkg_id")
    private Long pkgId; // corresponds to PK type of Package
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TEAM")
public class Team { 
    @EmbeddedId
    private TeamId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("pkgId") // m
    private Package package;

    private String name;

    private long filesCount;

    ...
}
```

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.